# Sleep Thread With IF condition in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my C# windows form, I want to set notification label with loop and thread before fill the data into data grid view . for that I try to use below method and thread.

My Thread is

```
public void Run()
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("this is System Thread");
        m = new Dashboard();
        string text = "";
        Int32 a = 0;
        do
        {

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            notiCount++;
            /*Notifications ne = new Notifications(m.loadNotification);
            ne.Invoke(text);*/


            //Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
        while (notiCount <= 10) ;
    }
```

My method is

```
 private void loadINtransfer(string status)
    {
        Int32 x = 0;
        string text="";
        SystemThreadings s = new SystemThreadings();
        Thread t = new Thread(s.Run);
        t.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(100);
        do
        {
            if (s.notiCount == 0)
            {
                text = "Request Data";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                this.loadNotification(text);
                // MessageBox.Show("request");

            }
            else if (s.notiCount == 3)
            {
                text = "Fetching Data";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                //MessageBox.Show("request");
                this.loadNotification(text);
            }
            else if (s.notiCount == 6)
            {
                text = "Loading Data";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                this.loadNotification(text);
                //MessageBox.Show("loading");

            }
            else if (s.notiCount == 9)
            {
                text = "Done";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                this.loadNotification(text);
                //MessageBox.Show("done");
            }
            //Thread.Sleep(200);
        }
        while (s.notiCount != 10);

        //Thread.Sleep(5000);
        MessageBox.Show("attach");
        dt = dl.loadTransfer(status);   
        dgvDashboard.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvDashboard.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

but it only show `Done` part. other if parts are passing but not show. And I want to wait some time the all parts before load data to grid view. how can I do this. Please help Me.

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` isn't the right way to be writing code like this. It looks like this might be a good fit for `BackgroundWorker` (which some people will also criticize because "everything should be `async`" but I think still has good use cases that make sense, such as here)

Comment: (And the reason that things aren't showing up is that `Thread.Sleep` doesn't *release* the UI thread to go and do other things, such as *redrawing*)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever can't I do something in this way?

Comment: Since Servy wants this clarified - I've assumed in my answer that the only `Thread.Sleep` calls intended to be in your final solution were the ones inside `loadINtransfer` - the ones inside `Run` are meant to be "things happen here"? (And, in fact, the whole loop in there is meant to represent "ongoing work with updates to indicate how far we're got so far")

Answer (score 0):

As I alluded to in the comments, this is pretty well a poster-child use case for `BackgroundWorker`. I created a new Windows Forms application, added a button and a label (I didn't bother to rename them), and then double-clicked the button to add an event handler. After adding the `BackgroundWorker` code, this is what `Form1.cs` ended up looking like:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += Bw_DoWork;
            bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bw.ProgressChanged += Bw_ProgressChanged;
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("attach");
            //dt = dl.loadTransfer(status);
            //dgvDashboard.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            //dgvDashboard.DataSource = dt;
        }

        private void Bw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ProgressPercentage == 0)
            {
                label1.Text = "Request Data";
            }
            else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 3)
            {
                label1.Text = "Fetching Data";
            }
            else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 6)
            {
                label1.Text = "Loading Data";
            }
            else if (e.ProgressPercentage == 9)
            {
                label1.Text = "Done";
            }
        }

        private void Bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            int notiCount = 0;
            do
            {

                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                notiCount++;

                worker.ReportProgress(notiCount);
            }
            while (notiCount <= 10);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that we're not having to sleep or wait on the UI thread. When progress has been made, we're *notified* and can access the UI to update it. And when the work is complete, we again get notified.

The only `Thread.Sleep` we have is within the background worker, and I assume there is standing for actual useful work being done.

You **absolutely should not** have any `Thread.Sleep` calls in any constrained context such as the UI thread, where there aren't likely to be any *other* threads available to service other uses which may want to use *your* thread whilst you're just blocking it. Even `Sleep`ing a threadpool thread is acting as a bad "team player" in modern multi-threaded applications.

Comment: BGW is created for doing *CPU bound work* in another thread.  Not for performing some operation every second.  a *Timer* is the tool expressly created for performing an operation every second.

Comment: @Servy - I've already tried to be clear that I'm assuming that the `Thread.Sleep` in the worker is a stand-in for real work. Admittedly, the OP could have come up with this as a stand-in for timers, but do you really think it's likely that they'll be reporting different "status"s *just* as a timer operation? I read their code as "I'm wanting to do something off the UI thread but provide status updates as that progresses" - do you have a different (sane) interpretation?

Comment: @Servy - exception to my above interpretation - if this is a [Speed-up loop](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Speedup-Loop) - i.e. it is purely designed to waste time and they'll "optimize" the code later to reduce the sleeps. In that case, yes, timer is the right tool.